# How to handle encrypt and decrypt file in ASP.NET core web API

Tags: c#, rest, .net-core

What is the best way to implement encrypt and decrypt file content using asp.net core web API?
It should be compatible with the swagger also. I have tried this the same way as encrypt a string, but there is a limitation of size length or incomplete file sent over API.
I require to encrypt at the client end before API call via swagger or postman and be decrypt at service end.
File content encrypts at the client end then only data at transmission will safe.

I have tried below

```
public static string encrypt(string PlainText, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
      {
          string sR = string.Empty;

          byte[] plainBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PlainText);

          GcmBlockCipher cipher = new GcmBlockCipher(new AesFastEngine());
          AeadParameters parameters =
                       new AeadParameters(new KeyParameter(key), 128, iv, null);

          cipher.Init(true, parameters);

          byte[] encryptedBytes = new byte[cipher.GetOutputSize(plainBytes.Length)];
          Int32 retLen = cipher.ProcessBytes
                         (plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length, encryptedBytes, 0);
          cipher.DoFinal(encryptedBytes, retLen);
          sR = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes, Base64FormattingOptions.None);


          return sR;
      }
```

Comment: `there is a limitation of size length or incomplete file sent over API`  what do you mean ? What exactly occurs when you try and send an encrypted string ? Do you get the same error when you send an unencrypted string ?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at this link: https://github.com/2Toad/Rijndael256/issues/13#issuecomment-637724412
It uses the [`Rijndael`/`AES`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) cypher to encrypt the data you put in.

In the Github issue you will find the following code:

```
public static class CipherHelper
{
    // This constant is used to determine the keysize of the encryption algorithm in bits.
    // We divide this by 8 within the code below to get the equivalent number of bytes.
    private const int Keysize = 256;

    // This constant determines the number of iterations for the password bytes generation function.
    private const int DerivationIterations = 1000;

    public static string Encrypt(string plainText, string passPhrase)
    {
        // Salt and IV is randomly generated each time, but is preprended to encrypted cipher text
        // so that the same Salt and IV values can be used when decrypting.  
        var saltStringBytes = Generate256BitsOfRandomEntropy();
        var ivStringBytes = Generate256BitsOfRandomEntropy();
        var plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
        using (var password = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passPhrase, saltStringBytes, DerivationIterations))
        {
            var keyBytes = password.GetBytes(Keysize / 8);
            var engine = new RijndaelEngine(256);
            var blockCipher = new CbcBlockCipher(engine);
            var cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(blockCipher, new Pkcs7Padding());
            var keyParam = new KeyParameter(keyBytes);
            var keyParamWithIV = new ParametersWithIV(keyParam, ivStringBytes, 0, 32);

            cipher.Init(true, keyParamWithIV);
            var comparisonBytes = new byte[cipher.GetOutputSize(plainTextBytes.Length)];
            var length = cipher.ProcessBytes(plainTextBytes, comparisonBytes, 0);

            cipher.DoFinal(comparisonBytes, length);
            //                return Convert.ToBase64String(comparisonBytes);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(saltStringBytes.Concat(ivStringBytes).Concat(comparisonBytes).ToArray());
        }
    }

    public static string Decrypt(string cipherText, string passPhrase)
    {
        // Get the complete stream of bytes that represent:
        // [32 bytes of Salt] + [32 bytes of IV] + [n bytes of CipherText]
        var cipherTextBytesWithSaltAndIv = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
        // Get the saltbytes by extracting the first 32 bytes from the supplied cipherText bytes.
        var saltStringBytes = cipherTextBytesWithSaltAndIv.Take(Keysize / 8).ToArray();
        // Get the IV bytes by extracting the next 32 bytes from the supplied cipherText bytes.
        var ivStringBytes = cipherTextBytesWithSaltAndIv.Skip(Keysize / 8).Take(Keysize / 8).ToArray();
        // Get the actual cipher text bytes by removing the first 64 bytes from the cipherText string.
        var cipherTextBytes = cipherTextBytesWithSaltAndIv.Skip((Keysize / 8) * 2).Take(cipherTextBytesWithSaltAndIv.Length - ((Keysize / 8) * 2)).ToArray();

        using (var password = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passPhrase, saltStringBytes, DerivationIterations))
        {
            var keyBytes = password.GetBytes(Keysize / 8);
            var engine = new RijndaelEngine(256);
            var blockCipher = new CbcBlockCipher(engine);
            var cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(blockCipher, new Pkcs7Padding());
            var keyParam = new KeyParameter(keyBytes);
            var keyParamWithIV = new ParametersWithIV(keyParam, ivStringBytes, 0, 32);

            cipher.Init(false, keyParamWithIV);
            var comparisonBytes = new byte[cipher.GetOutputSize(cipherTextBytes.Length)];
            var length = cipher.ProcessBytes(cipherTextBytes, comparisonBytes, 0);

            cipher.DoFinal(comparisonBytes, length);
            //return Convert.ToBase64String(saltStringBytes.Concat(ivStringBytes).Concat(comparisonBytes).ToArray());

            var nullIndex = comparisonBytes.Length - 1;
            while (comparisonBytes[nullIndex] == (byte)0)
                nullIndex--;
            comparisonBytes = comparisonBytes.Take(nullIndex + 1).ToArray();


            var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(comparisonBytes, 0, comparisonBytes.Length);

            return result;
        }
    }

    private static byte[] Generate256BitsOfRandomEntropy()
    {
        var randomBytes = new byte[32]; // 32 Bytes will give us 256 bits.
        using (var rngCsp = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            // Fill the array with cryptographically secure random bytes.
            rngCsp.GetBytes(randomBytes);
        }
        return randomBytes;
    }
}
```

To make this code work, you will need to install the `BouncyCastle.NetCore` NuGet package.

This code helps you to encrypt and decrypt a string by using a password.
In your case, if you somehow know the password at both sides of the request (send-side and receive-side) than this should be able to work.